# How should I start this project in Android?

Tags: android

> Design/develop a simple prototype for file encryption. Prototype will upload image file from internal/external memory and will save in YoApp/test folder with encrypted file name (you don't need to encrypt file itself). For encryption you can use any simple and existing algorithm. Project will have single screen with upload button.

Comment: You start by downloading Eclipse, the Android SDK, and running the first tutorials.

Comment: i know that...But i confused in mentioned question.. how i am start the application. plz help me

Comment: My point is, you don't even know how to build an initial app, and you're looking for guidance in advanced features like device storage, image management, file upload (to external server), and encryption.  4 things that all have their own learning curve.

Comment: If you don't know how to start a complex task, you break it down into smaller pieces. If those smaller pieces are too daunting, you break them down further. The point is, you have to start working on some of those smaller pieces, even if you don't know how to do the rest yet. Don't expect any of us to help you if you aren't willing to prove to us that you can code a little bit and post that code as proof in your question.  If you don't know the basics of Java and Android (but you somehow think you that you do know), our technical suggestions will largely fall on death ears anyway.

Comment: (continued...) And the next thing you'll ask us for is the code. But of course, you'll ask for it in the most counter-productive way. You'll use abbreviations such as "plz". You won't bother to capitalize your sentences properly. You'll say it's really important and that you'll really be grateful. And you'll somehow think that the most desperate your pleas sound, the more likely we'll want to help you (which by the way, won't be the case).

Comment: Thank You so much Stephan Branczyk..i think you say true..first of all i clear all the concepts of my project and then actual start working on my project...thnks again for give the suggestion....